# Redirecting from web root and www to a specified subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What's the best way to redirect from web root (e.g., example.com) and the www subdomain (e.g., www.example.com) to a specified subdomain? I've not got great access to the server I'm working on, so editing .htaccess or similar would probably be the most practical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That'll do a 301 redirect and will include anything after the initial /, so `example.com/page.html` will go to `subdomain.example.com/page.html`

Comment: Thanks - and I guess this is the best way to perform such a redirect? The website I've inherited is currently redirecting via a hack in index.php in webroot

Comment: Oh, and would the redirect be visible to the end user? i.e., would they see example.com (or www.example.com) in the address bar, or would they see subdomain.example.com?

Comment: Yeah, redirects are usually best done in .htaccess, I believe Apache won't even pass the request to PHP if it sees a matching redirect. That makes it a bit faster.

Comment: And yeah, it's a 301 redirect, so their URL will update in the user's browser.

Comment: Thanks again. What I'm really after, though, is an invisible redirect: in other words, the user goes to example.com or www.example.com and is redirected to subdomain.example.com, but the URL that displays in the user's browser remains as the URL that the user originally entered. Is this possible?

Comment: Ah yep, but that's called a Rewrite, not a redirect. I believe if you remove the "R=301," from the last line I posted it should do the job, so `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.example.com/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot edit configuration files, but can upload files to the root directory via FTP, you can also do it with severside script. In PHP, for example in an index.php:

```
<?php header("Location: http://sub.domain.com/"); ?>
```